GeoPandas dataframe to JSON gives type error: Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable
I'm creating a plugin and within the code I have a GeoPandas geodateframe created from a QGIS Vector layer which I need to reformat back into a QGIS vector layer. To create a vector layer from a geodataframe I will first need to transform the GeoPandas dataframe to a json. However, when I apply the function to_json on the geodataframe I get the error:
TypeError: Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable

This is the code:
    # Create a new QgsProject. Reads and writes project states
    project = QgsProject.instance()

    # Get layer object
    selected_layer_name = self.dlg.LayerName.currentLayer().name()
    selected_layer = project.mapLayersByName(selected_layer_name)[0]
 
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(selected_layer.getFeatures())

    # Create new qgs layer from dataframe
    vl = QgsVectorLayer(gdf.to_json(), "jsondata", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

What does cause this error, and how can I create a QGIS-Vector layer from the GeoPandas dataframe without getting the QVariant-error?

With the help of @Bera and @couteau I figured out that in the data were 'NULL'-values, which caused the error TypeError: Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable
I adjusted my code by checking all columns if there are any instances of QVariants and if so, the values are transformed into np.NAN
This is the code:
        # Create a new QgsProject. Reads and writes project states
        project = QgsProject.instance()

        # Get selected layer object from QGIS-instance
        selected_layer_name = self.dlg.LayerName.currentLayer().name()
        selected_layer = project.mapLayersByName(selected_layer_name)[0]

        # Create geopandas dataframe from QGIS-vector-layer, set the crs to the relevant layer
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(selected_layer.getFeatures(), crs= selected_layer.crs().authid())

        # Find and convert the QVariants
        for col in gdf.columns:  # For each column
            if gdf[col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, QVariant)).any():  # Check if any value in col is QVariant
                # When found, convert it to a np.NAN-type
                gdf[col] = [np.NAN if isinstance(x, QVariant) else x for x in gdf[col]]

        # Create new qgs layer from dataframe and add as layer to QGIS-instance
        vl = QgsVectorLayer(gdf.to_json(), "myjson", "ogr")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)


However, even though this is now working, I will probably need to adjust the code to handle QVariant-values (which are real values) separated from NULL-Values (which are also QVariants).

You probably have a QVariant data type somewhere in your dataframe.
Try this:
import geopandas as gpd
layer = iface.activeLayer()


#############Create a geodataframe from a vector layer added to the map ###########################

#List all features attributes and geometries

data = []
for row in layer.getFeatures():
    data.append(f.attributes()+[f.geometry().asWkt()])

#Create a geodataframe from the list
df = gpd.pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=layer.fields().names()+["wkt"])
df["geometry"] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df.wkt)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=df.geometry, crs=layer.crs().authid())

#df.to_json() is working

df.at[0, "objektidentitet"] = QVariant("test") #Set the first value in column objektidentitet to QVariant
#df.to_json()
#TypeError: Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable

#Find and convert the QVariants
for col in df.columns: #For each column
    if df[col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, QVariant)).any(): #Check if any row is QVariant
        #print(col)
        #When found, convert it to a normal dtype using .value()
        df[col] = [x.value() if isinstance(x, QVariant) else x for x in df[col]]

df.to_json() #Now it is working


Thank you! I will check it out!

Unfortunately I still get the same error when I adjust my code accordingly. I created a geopandas dataframe according to your code and and then applied #Find and convert the QVariants. However, I still get the TypeError:Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable

Could it have something to do with the geopandas engine 'Fiona'? Testwise I exported the dataframe (created from the QGIS vector layer) to a shapefile and I get the error 'Invalid field type'. However, when I export the dataframe with the engine Pyogrio no errors occur.

What if you add  df[col] = df[col].astype(obj) below the df[col] = [x.value() if isinstance(x, QVariant) else x for x in df[col]] row?

You mean, I should define each column accoding to their type, or what do you mean with 'obj'? Can you explain it?

Another detail which may be important: the geometry type is of multilinestring z.  Is that probably a problem here?

I think .astype(obj) should work for all columns, just check if .to_json() is working afterwards. Then you should  define each column accoding to their type, as you say

Mh, this is not a solution which works in my context, as this is a part of a plugin, it needs to set the datatypes automatically, but i did try the solution by adding astype(object), just for testing. Unfortunatley it still doesn't work, I still get the same error, even after transforming all columns to object-type.

And I think it really has to do with 'NULL'-values, as the column, which is printed, contains NULL-values. So I will need to take about that

@Bera is correct that you must have QVariant objects in the data read from your layer. The most likely (possibly only?) reason is that the underlying data source has NULL values for some feature attributes. Qgis/Qt will convert most QVariants to their corresponding python datatypes, but NULLs in the data are left as NULL QVariants. If that is indeed the situation, you can replace just the NULLs with pd.NA or another useful value. E.g., for pd.NA you can try:
from qgis.core import NULL
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(selected_layer.getFeatures()).map(lambda x: pd.NA if x == NULL else x)


Thank you for trying to help! Unfortunately the map function is not implemented for geodataframes and as such this throws the error GeoDataFrame has no attribute 'map'

You need at least pandas 2.2.1 (and a compatible GeoPandas version) for map to be available. For older versions, you can use mapapply or, as @bera suggests, a column by column apply.

Thank you for the further information! I used apply yesterday, but in the end came up with another solution (see below). As I'm building a Plug-In for QGIS, I'm using it's built-in python Version, which is 3.9., Therefore I guess I have to use an old geopandas version as well.
